# How to update QLabel on QSortFilterProxyModel update

Tags: python, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I've implemented a custom QSortFilterProxyModel class which I use to display data in a QTableView.  I've overwritten the filterAcceptsRow function so users can enter a complex filter to filter in the data.  This works great and the QTableView is updating accordingly.
Below the QTableView I also want to display the number of entries that match the filter in a QLabel.

```
self.proxyModel = CustomSortFilterProxyModel()
self.table = QTableView()
self.table.setModel(self.proxyModel)
            

self.filterMatchLabel = QLabel("0")
statisticsLayout.addWidget(self.filterMatchLabel,60)
```

I know I can retrieve the RowCount from the model, but what is the proper way to subscribe on changes in the model?

According to the Data-Model-View principle, it sounds like the text with the number should be a custom view for the model.  Is this the correct way?
If so, how do I start creating my own View for a QSortFilterProxyModel?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Can't you just connect to the [`rowsInserted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) and [`rowsRemoved`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsRemoved) signals of the model?

Comment: _users can enter a complex filter_ Use the `editingFinished` signal of this input field to read the rows number of the model and update the label.

Comment: After some research into the rowsInserted and rowsRemoved I got it working and it's indeed exactly what I needed.  Thanks